# User logging into wordpress via permalink redirects to user-logged-in page but chrome console shows 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress, ssl, authentication, https, permalinks

When a user logs into wordpress via a friendly permalink url, the user is redirected to the logged in page, but a css stylesheet shows an err_connection_refused error in chrome.

When the user is in the logged in page, looking at the chrome network panel, it shows that the permalink page has a 500 internal server error, and the styleshet that is loaded after it shows a connection refused.

Everything else loads fine after it, but I'm thinking that this 500 internal server error is causing the stylesheet not to load properly.

Thanks.

I forgot to mention this only happens on macs.  Windows chrome loads fine every time.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that the same stylesheet is loaded fine everytime on the front page via the www.domain.com, probably because the user doesn't have to login.

Comment: I've tried seeing chrome://net-internals and capturing events when loading the page, but the only error it shows is a -102 err_connection_refused. No other clues to it.

Comment: When I clear the browser history, restart chrome, clear the history again, reopen chrome and load the permalink and login, the issue is reproducible every time on first load.  When I refresh the page, the stylesheet loads.  Only on the first page load after clearing history, does the problem show.